# Signal R transports undefined error

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I'm having issues with SignalR in a .Net web application I'm working on, keep getting this error:

Unhandled exception at line 4, column 9 in http://localhost:61962/signalr/connect?transport=foreverFrame&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=vMIgPIvxZ6BztpbQcSy+QpESYqkxMUHWf30o9QIoVrT2uKdRcsAhTJUWTuBzngKLRmMhrOjaKsRzIEGeYk+pW1Ci7x7cV8XgbP1/h6kB4u+hHMMWMZ/HivMbrqcW1L+I&connectionData=[{"name":"procevents"}]&tid=4&frameId=1

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'transports' of undefined or null reference

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>SignalR Forever Frame Transport Stream</title>
<script>
    var $ = window.parent.jQuery,
        ff = $ ? $.signalR.transports.foreverFrame : null,
        c =  ff ? ff.getConnection('1') : null,
        r = ff ? ff.receive : function() {};
    ff ? ff.started(c) : '';
```

This happens shortly after starting my hub...

```
hub = $.connection.RequestLogsHub;
$.connection.hub.start();
```

Usually that error occurs a second or two after I call start(). It displays the error with the generated forever frame code above (this isn't code I wrote).

The error doesn't seem to affect anything and I think it appears in Internet Explorer only. My signalR code seems to work fine as well, it's just an annoying error that I need to click through, which isn't going to be OK to release to users like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error... for some reason there were some repeated @Script.Render lines at the top and the bottom of the page. I think the bottom ones were undoing/replacing some of the objects already loaded. Moving everything to the top and eliminating duplicates resolves this.

Comment: Flag as [answered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) please.